# C# "Enum" Serialization - Deserialization to Static Instance

Tags: c#, serialization, static, enums

Suppose you have the following class:

```
class Test : ISerializable {

  public static Test Instance1 = new Test {
    Value1 = "Hello"
    ,Value2 = 86
  };
  public static Test Instance2 = new Test {
    Value1 = "World"
    ,Value2 = 26
  };

  public String Value1 { get; private set; }
  public int Value2 { get; private set; }

  public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
    //Serialize an indicator of which instance we are - Currently 
    //I am using the FieldInfo for the static reference.
  }
}
```

I was wondering if it is possible / elegant to deserialize to the static instances of the class?

Since the deserialization routines (I'm using BinaryFormatter, though I'd imagine others would be similar) look for a constructor with the same argument list as `GetObjectData()`, it seems like this can't be done directly . . Which I would presume means that the most elegant solution would be to actually use an `enum`, and then provide some sort of translation mechanism for turning an enum value into an instance reference.  However, I personally like that the "Enum"'s choices are directly linked with their data.

How might one go about this?

Comment: I'm trying to solve exactly this problem. Unfortunately, none of the answers are relevant. Everyone seems to have misunsertood the question. Did you find any reasonable solution?

Comment: BTW, I'm using "Symbols as extensible enums" (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/symbol.aspx). I'm trying to make them serializable without much success. I posted a question there to see if anybody will help.

Comment: jpbochi - You pretty much have to do galford13x's attribute "hack", or have some other way or mapping the objects, and only deal with the enum value when storing the data.  I never found a better way.

Comment: I sympathize with your request.
I am greatly missing the power that is present in Java enums :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need more data with with the Enums, consider using attributes.  Example below.

```
class Name : Attribute
{
    public string Text;

    public Name(string text)
    {
        this.Text = text;
    }
}


class Description : Attribute
{
    public string Text;

    public Description(string text)
    {
        this.Text = text;
    }
}
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
    [Name("FirstDayOfWeek")]
    [Description("This is the first day of 7 days")]
    Sunday = 1,

    [Name("SecondDayOfWeek")]
    [Description("This is the second day of 7 days")]
    Monday= 2,

    [Name("FirstDayOfWeek")]
    [Description("This is the Third day of 7 days")]
    Tuesday= 3,
}
```

Perhaps this will allow you to provide more information with the Enums.  You can access the attributes through reflection.  If you need an example to retrieve the attribute I can provide that as well but I'm trying to keep this somewhat short.

Comment: Well, this works, but it does require a lot of reflection and is not exactly what I was looking for.  But with a basic wrapper class, I do suppose it would be very close... the main thing that would be awkward is the name difference between the wrapper class and the enum.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I normally resolve this by by naming the Enum and appending Enum to the end.

Enum = DaysOfWeekEnum
Class Wrapper = DaysOfWeek

Comment: Another very convenient way to access the attribute method is through extensions.  If your interested in how to do that ask another question regarding extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx)...Suppose you have the following:

```
Enum myEnum{
   Foo = 1,
   Bar = 2,
   Baz = 3
};
```

Then

```
   myEnum myE = myEnum.Foo; /* Default! */
   myE = (myEnum)Enum.Parse(myE.GetType(), "Baz"); 
   /* Now, myE should be Baz! */
   Console.WriteLine("Enum Selected: {0}", myE.ToString());
```

The above sample serves to illustrate how to convert a string literal into an enum. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: That is a handy function, but unless you can associate more data than a name / index within the default Enum type, it's not exactly what I'm looking for.